# NativeScript crash on [runtime executeModule:@"./"]

Tags: nativescript

On IOS app when compiled and deployed over Test Flight from iTunes connect I get a crash on:

[runtime executeModule:@"./"];

It works fine if i run it directly from XCode or with a Adhoc certificate over Hockey App.

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper **production certificate** to create your **release** build and then submit to TestFlight in https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ (via XCode or Application loader). You can't use the Adhoc certificate to submit applications in TestFlight

> Once you have it open in Xcode, you have to go to your target's
>   General settings and pick a team. In 'Build Settings' there should be
>   a suitable 'iOS Developer' and 'Code Signing Identity'.
>
> From the top drop-down, select your target, and from the devices and
>   emulators, pick 'Generic iOS Device'.
>
> Then you should be able to select from the top menu Product > Archive.
>
> This makes an xcodearchive and opens it in the Xcode Organizer. The
>   Xcode Organizer displays a list with builds of your app. Pick the last
>   build and click Upload to App Store.... You should select a team again
>   and whether to include app symbols for your app. Next, you can see a
>   list with the binary information, entitlements, etc. Click Upload.
>
> If you upload successfully, you should be able to log in at
>   https://itunesconnect.apple.com and see your build in 'Activities'.
>   From there you can enable Test Flight beta testing or send it for
>   approval.

Comment: Hi. I tested and that still cause the crash i experience above.